# psycopg2 - acceptable date/datetime values

Tags: datetime, pandas, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 and sqlalchemy to insert data in a postgres db from xls files. I've previously been experiencing issues in inserting the 'date' columns which have been formatted as a number in excel. We have defined these columns as date type in postgres.
I have two issues here:
1. Some of the values in the date columns are empty. Pandas is converting those values to `NaT` or `NaN` but sqlalchemy and psycopg2 is not able to parse.

```
df = pd.read_excel(full_path, encoding='utf-8')
dict_items = df.to_dict(orient='records')
table = sql.Table(table_name, engine, schema='users')
connection.execute(table.insert().values(dict_items))

<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NaT"
```

I have converted the numbers into python dates via the code below but also had to make sure the dates are not greated then Pandas timestamp max because I previously got an 'Range Out of Bounds' for timestamp:

```
max_date = pd.Timestamp.max

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in date_cols:
        date_value = row[col]
        if not np.isnan(date_value):
            year, month, day, hour, minute, sec = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date_value, 0)
            py_date = "%02d.%02d.%04d" % (month, day, year)
            if py_date > str(max_date):
                df.loc[index, col] = pd.to_datetime(max_date)
            else:
                df.loc[index, col] = py_date
        if np.isnan(date_value):
            df.loc[index, col] = pd.to_datetime('01.12.2016')
```

Now I get the following error:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) integer out of range\n',)<traceback object at>
```

Could this be related to the last line of code, where I push in the `01.12.2016`? Is there some way of tracing where the problem lies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIUC you can use `df[i] = pd.to_datetime(df[i], format="%dd.%m.%Y", errors='coerce')` for convert no datetime values to `NaT`

Comment: @jezrael I tried that before but psycopg2 then gives me an error, see above.

Comment: @jezrael is 'NaT' or 'NaN' for that matter a hack as a database value? I'm unsure if the issue lies with psycopg2 or postgres

Comment: I changed the information as I was able to convert the excel number dates to python dates.

Answer (score 4):

To fix the issues with the nan's and nat's just change them to None in the dataframe and then they should get inserted without complaint. It solved my issue with this.

```
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

I got this solution from the [postgres message board](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/55D6639A.8040503@aklaver.com) where they show a small example of the nans getting changed to None

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate approach that worked for me

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace({np.nan: None})
```